# getting status name corresponding to the member_id

Tags: c#, mysql, join

This is my datastructure

```
                 memberstable
                       member_id

                 membertomshiptable 
                          member_id   
                          membertomshiptable_id
                          memberstatustype_id


                membershipstatustable
                      membershipstatustype_id
                      membershipstatus_name
```

is it possibel to get the membershipstatus name corresponding to member id in members table

would any one pls help me on this...

Comment: a basic sql join. try go google n see how to join tables with mysql.

Comment: select mshipstatustype_Name FROM mshipstatustypes innerjoin membertomships on membertomships.mshipStatusType_Id = mshipstatustypes.mshipStatusType_Id innerjoin members where members.member_Id = membertomships.member_Id  i have done this one but it gives error near membertomships

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Mysql JOIN syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html)

```
SELECT st.membershipstatus_name FROM memberstable m
LEFT JOIN membertomshiptable sh ON m.member_id = sh.member_id
LEFT JOIN membershipstatustable st ON sh.memberstatustype_id = st.membershipstatustype_id
WHERE m.member_id = [member_id_here]
```

But this will return you all the shipping items for all members. You will need to restrict with some WHERE conditions to get info for certain member or certain package(shipping item)

Comment: where i have to put the "where " condition i wnat to get status name for particular member in members table

Comment: At the end put: WHERE m.member_id = [member_id_here]